# Flask SocketIO authenticate on connect event by sending token

Tags: python, authentication, flask-socketio

Currently after a `user` logs in, I return a `token` using `JSON`. Subsequently they must make a request to the `index` page  and pass the `token` in the `HTTP Authorisation header`.

The `index.html` page contains the following:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

socket.on('connect', function() {          
          socket.emit('join', {room: 'venue_1'}); 
});
```

If the `user` follows this process of events then connection to `socket` is only possible after they `login`. However, I am trying to prevent against the situation where someone may just create a `html` file containing the above code and not first go through the `login` step.

**Server Code**

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():

    # Can anything be done here to verify a user?

    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})
```

Is there a way I can pass a `token` to the above `connect` event so that I can verify the user there. If the `token` ended up being invalid, I could maybe run a `disconnect` call.

Or does this need to occur when I do the following call?

```
socket.emit('join', {room: 'venue_1', token:'token1234'});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for Flask-SocketIO includes a section on [Authentication](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#authentication).

The solution is based on the availability of the HTTP context (user session and cookies) inside your SocketIO handlers. If you are using Flask-Login to manage the user session, then the `current_user` context variable is available in your socket handlers. For example:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated()
        return  # do not respond or disconnect
    # user is authenticated
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})
```

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. I don't know a great deal about `Javascript` and was wondering should I simply set a `cookie` before connecting to the `socket` as such: `document.cookie="token=token123"`, then try to retrieve it in the `connect` event on the `server`? I've been using `Token Based Authentication` as specified in your blog.

Comment: There isn't a single way to do this. One option that I think makes sense for this type of auth flow is to have the client authenticate with the server before opening the socket connection. In the auth route in the server you can set a cookie (or let Flask-Login do it for you if you prefer). Then when the socket connection is established you have access to the cookie to validate that the user is known. So I'd say don't worry about Javascript, you don't have to do anything auth related on the client side if you don't want to.